# Discord.py bot isn't mentioning users properly

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a bot using discord.py, and I have a happy birthday command where you can say
`{prefix} hbd <@user>`, ie +hbd @friend. My problem is that when the bot mentions the aforementioned user, the user isn't actually pinged, despite the mention showing up in the embed message.
Code:

```py
@bot.command() # NUMBER 5
async def hbd(ctx, user: discord.User):
    target = user
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Happy Birthday!", description=f"Happy Birthday {target.mention}", color=discord.Color.green())
    em.set_footer(text=f"Wishes from {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=em)
```

Result of command:
[Image of result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJFlp.png)
In the example, I mentioned myself, as seen in the message I sent. But when the bot tries to mention me, it doesn't highlight, nor does it ping the user (I got the help of my friend to test this). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try `f"Happy Birthday <@!${target.id}>"`?

Comment: Mentions in an embed will never ping the user, if you mean that. Do you have another message sent with the embed?

Comment: How do you mean? I do have a help command that sends as an embed, but that's about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinging is not possible in embeds, however you can add

```py
@bot.command() # NUMBER 5
async def hbd(ctx, user: discord.User):
    target = user
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Happy Birthday!", description=f"Happy Birthday {target.mention}", color=discord.Color.green())
    em.set_footer(text=f"Wishes from {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

    await ctx.channel.send(f'Happy BIRTHDAY! <@!{target.id}', embed=em)
```

It pings the user outside the message

Hope this helps in some way or form!

Comment: `await ctx.channel.send(f'Happy BIRTHDAY! {target.mention}', embed=em)` would be more discord-py-thonic.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried not doing `target = user`? That might fix it!

```py
@bot.command() # NUMBER 5
async def hbd(ctx, user: discord.User):
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Happy Birthday!", description=f"Happy Birthday {user.mention}", color=discord.Color.green())
    em.set_footer(text=f"Wishes from {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: By the way, yes you can ping users/roles/channels inside an embed as long that it isn't on the "title" field.

Comment: I don't understand how using the raw parameter input instead of assigning it to a variable would fix things... you say there is a way to ping outside of the embed title, do you know how?

Comment: Yeah @DavyJonesStockings its literally what i've shown on the response above.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if your original example had worked.

Comment: Maybe its the version he is using, it works for me.